# Python pandas - detect and convert numpy.ndarray columns to list columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

We have the following dtypes in our pandas dataframe:

```
>>> results_df.dtypes
_id                              int64
playerId                         int64
leagueId                         int64
firstName                       object
lastName                        object
fullName                        object
shortName                       object
gender                          object
nickName                        object
height                         float64
jerseyNum                       object
position                        object
teamId                           int64
updated            datetime64[ns, UTC]
teamMarket                      object
conferenceId                     int64
teamName                        object
updatedDate                     object
competitionIds                  object
dtype: object
```

The `object` types are not helpful in the `.dtypes` output here since some columns are ordinary strings (eg. `firstName`, `lastName`), whereas other columns are more complex (`competitionIds` is an numpy.ndarray of int64s).

We'd like to convert `competitionIds`, and any other columns that are `numpy.ndarray` columns, into list columns, without explicitly passing `competitionIds`, since it's not always known which columns are the `numpy.ndarray` columns. So, even though this works: `results_df['competitionIds'] = results_df['competitionIds'].apply(list)`, it doesn't entirely solve the problem because I'm explicitly passing `competitionIds` here, whereas we need to automatically detect which columns are the `numpy.ndarray` columns.

Comment: Something like `all(isinstance(x, np.ndarray) for x in column_that's_object)` or so?

Comment: Or, if the contents of a column are known to be consistent, just check the first element?

Comment: `column_that's_object` here would be a list of column names?

Comment: It might be one of the dtype scalar instances then, not `np.ndarray`.  what does `type(...)` for the first element of the column give?

Comment: The columns `should` be consistent but there is some missing data in these tables. `competitionIds` in particular has empty / missing values.

Comment: No, it's one of the columns you're inspecting. You'll have to iterate through them.

Comment: @MadPhysicist `type()` gives me `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. The "missing" values are actually just empty arrays that also return `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`, which is good - seems like I could loop the columns and look for these..

Comment: I think you should post an MCVE. Say a 3x3 DF with one column that you'd like to identify.

Comment: An `object` dtype column can contain anything, even different things in each row.  The `isinstance` test is needed for a representative element if not all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas treats just about anything that isn't an int, float or category as an "object" (including `list`s!). So the best way to go about this is to look at the type of an actual element of the column:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([{'str': 'a', 'arr': np.random.randint(0, 4, (4))} for _ in range(3)])

df.apply(lambda c: list(c) if isinstance(c[0], np.ndarray)  else c)
```

This will prevent you from converting other types that you may want to keep in place (e.g. sets) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a toy example of what I'm thinking:

```py
import numpy as np

data = {'col1':np.nan, 'col2':np.ndarray(0)}

for col in data:
    print(isinstance(data[col],np.ndarray))
```

resulting in:

```
#False
#True
```